# Change the color of an object with class

Tags: javascript, html

I want to change the color of all elements with class='nav-button' using JS. I've tried the code below, but it doesn't seem to work. I think it doesn't recognize 'style' in the 4th line. Not sure why, I've seen plenty of examples where people use it.

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('nav-button')

for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].firstChild.style.color = 'red';
}
```

Any solutions?

Edit: the first child item is necessary because there is an  element inside of the nav-button

Comment: Remove `firstChild` and your code will work. Like this `elements[i].style.color = 'red';`

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need `firstChild` as the code below worked for me.

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('nav-button')

Array.from(elements).forEach(el => el.style.color = 'red')
```

Comment: I needed firstChild, because there was a <a> element inside the 'nav-button'

Answer (score 1):

The `getElementsByClassName` function returns an HTMLCollection instead of an array, so you can't iterate through it. You can achieve it by spreading the collection values in an array, like this:

```
[...elements]
```

And then you can use it like this: `[...elements].forEach(el => el.style.color = 'red')`

Comment: And that collection has length and is array-like so this is not accurate. Nothing wrong with OP's `for` loop approach

Comment: True, I mistook it for the NodeList, which I thought you couldn't loop through, but you can too, my bad

Comment: People were looping through them long before spread, forEach and `for of` all came along

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to change the color of the firstChild of each element with class `nav-button`, try using `firstElementChild` instead of `firstChild`:

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('nav-button')

for (let e of elements) {
    e.firstElementChild.style.color = 'red';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate on the collection and you don't need to use a variable for that:

```
for (let el of document.getElementsByClassName('nav-button')) {
    el.style.color = 'red'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have a purpose using "firstChild" or maybe you copy pasted from somewhere.
But, simply you have to remove `firstChild` on line 4!

```js
const elements = document.getElementsByClassName('nav-button');

for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].style.color = 'red';
};
```

```html
<button class="nav-button">1</button>
<button class="nav-button">2</button>
<button class="nav-button">3</button>
```